# How do you add the Jiggly Armature code to Blender as an add-on?

Tags: armature, add-on

So pardon the ignorance of a newbie, however I stumbled across the add-on called Jiggly Armature and upon further investigation it is in raw code so my next thought was, where do I enter this code and what affect will it have on the function of Blender, aside from its stated function? Would it be better for a newbie to just use the collision method I read about to obtain the same jiggly effect? below are the links regarding this post , the link to the collision method is inappropriate for work or minors .

Comment: Can you provide a link to the code? Without seeing it, it is impossible to know how to use it.

Comment: sure , http://cheece.github.io/JiggleArmature/

Comment: this is a link to the collision method I described in my question : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nkhXESF0jI&has_verified=1

Comment: you may want to be clear that that video is not really safe for people to click on at work.

Comment: Also I suggest adding another question asking for the best method for animating jiggle and describing your particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Addons are all just code, in one or more files, normally packaged up in zip archive. However if all the code is in one file, they don't need to be zipped up.

If you go to: https://github.com/cheece/JiggleArmature/blob/master/JiggleArmature.py and right click on the button in the top right that says raw, and select *save link as* you will download a file containing the addon code.

You can then install this like a normal addon. Bear in mind this hasn't been updated in 2 years, so it may have bugs. The addon metadata says it was created for 2.77. That said it will probably be ok in 2.79.

As for any side affects from the addon code, you would have to read the code and check it carefully, as with any other addon. I had a very quick skim and it looks like it just does what it says.